# Overriding equals in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

`CS` implements `kotlin.CharSequence`. The essence of it is here:

```
class CS  (val sequence: CharSequence = "") : CharSequence {
... override get/length in interface CharSequence 
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean =
            (this === other) || ((other is String) && this.sequence.equals(other))
}
```

The compiler objects to `CS("hello") == "hello"` as: *Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'CS' and 'String'*.  It has no problems with `CS("hello") == "hello" as Any` or `CS("hello").equals("hello")` which both work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "override get/length in interface CharSequence" is better done by using delegation: `: CharSequence by sequence`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I'm not certain of the reason for this error, but it might be related to a deeper problem with your approach…

In Kotlin (and Java), the `equals()` method has a fairly tight specification.  One condition is that it must be symmetric: whenever `a` and `b` are not null, `a.equals(b)` must always give the same result as `b.equals(a)`.

But your implementation fails this test, because `CS("abc").equals("abc")` returns `true`, while `"abc".equals(CS("ABC"))` is `false`.  That's because your class knows about `CharSequence`s such as `String`, but `String` does not know about your class.

There's no easy way around that.  In general, it's much safer to allow instances of a class to equal only instances of that class.  If you control both classes, then there are ways around that, but they're quite subtle and involved.  (Perhaps the best explanation is by [Martin Odersky et al](https://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html).)

So most implementations of `equals()` tend to work along these lines:

```
override fun equals(other: Any?)
    = (other is ThisClass)
    && field1 == other.field1
    && field2 == other.field2
    // ...
```

As I said, I don't know why the Kotlin compiler is complaining in your case.  It may be that it has spotted something of this problem, or it may be something unrelated.  But I don't think you're going to be able to fix your program in a way that equality checks will do what you want, so perhaps it's best to take this as a hint to try a slightly different approach!

Comment: Thanks, it does make sense that equality should be an equivalence relation - annoying as I might find it in this case.  My original class (in Java) provided a 'view' onto part of a String (and of course used .equals() explicitly so it all worked smoothly.  And it worked in C++ days.  An old dog must learn new tricks (or unlearn bad habits depending on point of view).

Comment: Kotlin's solution makes sense. There are three  sorts of equality. `===` tests if values are identical, `==` tests if they should be considered as equivalent instances (in some way).  The third sense is as an ordering, e.g  as used with <, >, etc.  `a.compareTo(b)` might give zero (i.e. equal) even though `a.equals(b)` might not.  The first could give case-blind comparisons for example where the second might not.  Kotlin's decision is not to provide a shorthand for a.compare(b) == 0.  I'll use an infix function `isLike` for that case.

Answer (score 3):

The `==` operator in Kotlin doesn't work if the types on both sides of the operation are known and different from each other.
For example:

```
3 == "Hello"
true == 5.0
// and so on
```

Will give a compile error because the compiler infers that operands are instances of different classes and therefore cannot be equal.

The only exception is if one side of the operator is a subclass of the other:

```
open class A
class B: A()
class C: A()

val c = C()
val b = B()
val a = A()

c == b
c == a // good
a == b // also good
```

In this case, `c == b` will give a compile error, while the other two operations will not.

That is why when you cast one side of the operation to `Any` it no longer gives an error since everything is a subtype of `Any`.

Answer (score 0):

@Michael mentioned in the comment that this operator is valid, so you can go  to the answer below:

I think, the error you get may be related to the fact that Kotlin has problems with inferring your data type. You are providing `Any` type as a parameter for the `equals(...)` method and comparing it with your class (`this`). Maybe try to cast the type like that:

```
this == (other as String)
```

or

```
this == (other as CharSequence)
```

I'm not sure if that's the correct approach, but maybe it will be a hint for you.

Comment: _"I'm not sure if triple equals operator === is available in Kotlin"_ [It is](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html).

Comment: Good to know @Michael. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Piotr, But it's not the code in `equals` I have problems with.  I expected `CS("hello") == "hello"` to be interpreted as  `CS("hello").equals("hello")` - which works when written explicitly.  So there, "hello" is being accepted belonging to a subclass of Any.

Comment: It is, but with a completely different meaning from JS.